# Invert indices of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I need to compare two lists (list1 and list2) on sign changes and I want to invert those indices in the second list that undergo sign changes. This means that I want to change the -4 and the -11 in list2 to 4 and 11. How can I do this?

```
list1 = [1,4,5,6,8,10]
list2 = [3,10,-4,7,-11,10]
```

Comment: By "undergo sign changes" you mean an element in `list2` have different sign than the element with the same index in `list1`?

Comment: What have you tried? Try taking a look at what `enumerate()` does

Comment: @zabop Yeah, that is indeed what I mean.

Comment: Maybe include a negative number in `list1` with a negative number in `list2` with the same index, so your example is clear, with an expected output? I'll then be able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can do this fairly straightforward with list comprehension:

```
list3 = [j*-1 if (i < 0 and j > 0) or (i > 0 and j < 0) else j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]

print(list3)

[3, 10, 4, 7, 11, 10]
```

Comment: Dont you think you need brackets between the conditions separated by the `or`?

Comment: @zabop Hmm good one! Not sure... Do you mean: list3 = [j*-1 if (i < 0 and j > 0) or (i > 0 and j < 0) else j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]? The output doesn't change in this case but if that's cleaner than I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. The output might not change in this case but I think there are cases when it would (`list1` does not currently have negative numbers for example, so the testing is not that thorough if you use the provided lists in the question).

Comment: @zabop I tried it by changing the second element in list1 to -4 and both the scenario with and without the additional brackets resulted in the same outcome. So I think it should be okay, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `zip(list1, list2)` and if a multiple of a pair is less than 0, change the sign of `list2` item, else keep the sign unchanged:

```
out = [(j*(-1) if i*j < 0 else j) for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output:

```
[3, 10, 4, 7, 11, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

n= len(list1) #length of list1 = length of list2

for i in range(n):   #iterating over the elements of list1 and list2 simultaneously

```
  if( (list1[i])*(list2[i]) <0):   #if corresponding elements of list1 and list2 are differently signed
     list1[i]=abs(list1[i])  #assign this element of list1 its absolute value
     list2[i]=abs(list2[i])  #assign this element of list2 its absolute value
```